# Expire Cookie on 7th day using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I've set cookie on my `user.php` but it does not work.

It was deleting when I close my browser. I want to set login cookie has expiration for 7 days.

**CODE THAT I'VE ADDED**

```
setcookie('email', $email,time()+3600*24*7);
setcookie('password', $password,time()+3600*24*7);
```

I have tried so many times to move and replace it on mycode it still does not work,  Where do I replace cookie on my code?

**CODE :**

login.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'config.php'; 
?>
<?php 
    if( !empty( $_POST )){
        try {
            $user_obj = new Cl_User();
            $data = $user_obj->login( $_POST );
            if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']){
                header('Location: home.php');
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    //print_r($_SESSION);
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']){
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Smart Login Page</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php require_once 'templates/ads.php';?>
        <div class="login-form">
            <?php require_once 'templates/message.php';?>
            <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
            <div class="form-header">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </div>
            <form id="login-form" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" autofocus> 
                <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> 
                <button class="btn btn-block bt-login" type="submit" id="submit_btn" data-loading-text="Signing In....">Sign in</button>
            </form>
            <div class="form-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        <a href="forget_password.php"> Forgot password? </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        <a href="register.php"> Sign Up </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

user.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * This User will have functions that hadles user registeration,
 * login and forget password functionality
 * @author muni
 * @copyright www.smarttutorials.net
 */
class Cl_User
{
    /**
     * @var will going contain database connection
     */
    protected $_con;

    /**
     * it will initalize DBclass
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $db = new Cl_DBclass();
        $this->_con = $db->con;
    }

    /**
     * This method will handle user login process
     * @param array $data
     * @return boolean true or false based on success or failure
     */
    public function login( array $data )
    {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
        if( !empty( $data ) ){

            // Trim all the incoming data:
            $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);

            // escape variables for security
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['password'] );


            if((!$email) || (!$password) ) {
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
            }
            $password = md5( $password );
            $query = "SELECT member_id, member_display_name, member_email, member_status, roles_id FROM fm_member where member_email = '$email' and member_pwd = '$password' ";
            //$query = "SELECT user_id, name, email, created, roles_id, id FROM users where email = '$email' and password = '$password'"
            $result = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            mysqli_close($this->_con);
            if( $count == 1){
                $_SESSION = $data;
                setcookie('email', $email,time()+3600*24*7); // This is cookie that i've added.
                setcookie('password', $password,time()+3600*24*7); // This is cookie that i've added.
                if($_SESSION['member_status'] == 'Activated') {
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                    return true;  
                } else {
                    throw new Exception( 'Your account is Deactiavted! <br> Please contact to Adminnistrator for more information.' );
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
                }
            }else{
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FAIL );
            }
        } else{
            throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
        }

    }


    /**
     * This handle sign out process
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do not set the users password in a cookie. Do not use md5 for passwords, use PHPs native password api http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: What is the "expires" value when you inspect the cookie in the browser? (e.g., for chrome: right click -> inspect -> Resources -> Cookies)

Comment: Expires value `2017-01-13T05:42:12.235Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to set the max lifetime of the session.
You can do this setting it with

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 604800);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 604800);
session_set_cookie_params(604800, "/"); 
session_start();
```

Comment: just before the `session_start()` (at line 2 on your php)

Comment: Login session it's gone I closed my browser.

Comment: obviously you have to do the `start_session()` on any page/server request and not just for the login.php; did you check that?

Comment: Yes, I checked it all.

Comment: add also `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 604800);` before your `session_start()`

Comment: on my login.php or user.php? or all of pages?

Comment: the following lines should be included in all of your pages:  
`ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 604800);  
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 604800);  
session_set_cookie_params(604800, "/");  
session_start();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100647/discussion-between-lexplatt-and-butter-toast).